# React Native. How to make parent element to response to onPress called in children

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I have two Views wrapped with TouchableOpacity, one in another. The green one, let's call it A(parent), and the blue one - B(child).

The Question: Is it possible to make both TouchableOpacity work when I press on B?

Little explanation - In my app I have something like little modal view, and when this modal is visible I want the following behaviour - when I press outside the modal I want this modal close (its like press on B) and other touchableOpacity, which lays below, fires too (like A)

[Here you can see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hBs1.png)

```
function Test() {
return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('green touch')}>
        <View style={{height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'green', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('blue touch')}>
                <View style={{height: 200, width: 200, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

}

Comment: exactly, what you want? plz describe....

Comment: @Kuldeep Patel I want to be able to control which TouchableOpacity will response to the onPress event.

Comment: Your question is very unclear

Comment: @D10S I rephrased the question. Hope it became more clear

Answer (score 0):

```
What I have understand from question. If any changes happen in child u want to pass the data or we can notify your parent. Right?

 * Create a function in your Parent.   

    const sendDataToParent = (value) => {  console.log("---value")};

* Pass it to ur child component.

<ChildComponent sendDataToParent={sendDataToParent}/>


*In your child component get it from props

  

      const Child =({sendDataToParent})=>{
        return <TouchableOpacity onPress=(sendDataToParent(pass your value))/>
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. I left a comment for D10S' answer with an explanation of behaviour I'm trying to implement

Answer (score 0):

Your question still doesn't make sense.
If you want both of them to act the same then you don't need 2 buttons.
If you want them to fire only when 'B' is pressed then you can make 'A' just a plain View with no `onPress` effect.

Comment: In my app I have something like little modal view, and when this modal is visible I want the following behaviour - when I press outside the modal I want this modal close (its like press on B) and other touchableOpacity, which lays below, fires too (like A)